# Command 'selenium test' not available in Spring Roo

Tags: selenium, spring-roo

when I try to run the command

```
roo> selenium test --controller ~.web.TimerController
```

I get the following error:

```
Command 'selenium test --controller ~.web.TimerController' was found but is not
currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Maybe you should `type 'help' then ENTER` :-)

Comment: Do the tests run outside of the Roo shell?  From the shell, if you type `mvn selenium:selenese` at the project base, does it work?

Comment: it does work! but actually the original command is working too today, and I don't know why since I didn't change anything. but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you first have to run "web mvc controller" then the selenium test is available. This is true for version 1.2.3-RELEASE. I'm unsure on the previous versions.